# Why is my Tickets controller create action failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Good afternoon!

I can't seem to find what the problem is here on my Tickets and I thought maybe getting another eye on it would help :). Also it is greatly appreciated for using your time to help me out.

All pages for my Tickets work correctly except for the Create action. The redirection even works correctly by going to the tickets_path after I hit Create Ticket for the New. However, it keeps flashing to Unable to submit ticket. and does not create the record in the table.

There are no errors however, the console shows the Parameters of the form in the log below.

```
# Controller
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :create]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.includes(:category, :user, :ticket_status)
    #authorize User
  end

  def show
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    #authorize @user
  end

  def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
    @ticket.ticket_status = TicketStatus.find_by_name("Open")
  end

  def edit
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    if @ticket.save
      redirect_to tickets_path, :notice => "Ticket Submitted."
    else
      redirect_to tickets_path, :alert => "Unable to submit ticket."
    end
  end

  def update
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
      redirect_to tickets_path, :notice => "Ticket updated."
    else
      redirect_to edit_ticket_path, :alert => "Unable to update ticket."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @ticket.destroy
    redirect_to tickets_path, :notice => "Ticket deleted."
  end

  private

    def set_ticket
      @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    end

    def ticket_params
      params[:ticket].permit(:ticket_status_id, :user_id, :category_id, :title, :description)
    end

end

# Model
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :category
   belongs_to :ticket_status
   validates_presence_of :title, presence: true
   validates_presence_of :description, presence: true
   validates_presence_of :user_id, presence: true
   validates_presence_of :category_id, presence: true
   validates_presence_of :ticket_status_id, presence: true
end

# Ticket _form partial
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <hr>
    <h3><%= content_for?(:title) ? content_for(:title) : "Progressor Admin" %>
    <span><%= link_to current_user.email, edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-user btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right', id: 'tooltip-profile', data: {toggle: 'tooltip', placement: 'right'}, :'data-original-title' => 'View Profile' %></span>
    </h3>
    <hr>

<%= render 'sidebar' %>

<div class="col-sm-9">
  <%= form_for @ticket do |f| %>
    <% if @ticket.errors.any? %>
      <div class="alert alert-error">
        <b><%= pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ticket from being saved:</b>

        <ul>
          <% @ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <table class="table panel">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :user_id, "User Name" %></td>
        <td><%= f.label current_user.name  %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :category_id, "In which area are you having an issue?" %></td>
        <td><%= f.select(:category_id, Category.order("name ASC").map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {}, {:class => 'form-control'}) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :ticket_status_id %></td>
        <td><%= f.select(:ticket_status_id, TicketStatus.order("position   ASC").map{|c[c.name, c.id] }, {}, {:class => 'form-control'}) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :title, "Ticket Title" %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control' %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :description, "Ticket Description" %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'form-control', :rows => "10"%></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <% if @ticket.id %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', @ticket, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', tickets_path, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div> <!-- col-sm-9 -->

# Development Log
```

```html
    Started POST "/tickets" for ip-address at 2014-11-22 13:41:59 -0600
    Processing by TicketsController#create as HTML
    Parameters:      {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"N9rBPw6v+T2OMnn7dQp8NsFC5saYuUQsP5pcXe5gfhQ=", "ticket"=>    {"category_id"=>"5", "ticket_status_id"=>"8", "title"=>"asdf", "description"=>"asdf"}, "commit"=>"Create Ticket"}
    [1m[36mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 13   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
    [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
    [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
    Redirected to /tickets
    Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)
```

Comment: Try create from `rails console` => `t = Ticket.create({"category_id"=>"5", "ticket_status_id"=>"8", "title"=>"asdf", "description"=>"asdf"}); t.erros` and look errors.

Comment: Please add your list of validations from your ticket class. And try the following command to inspect whats the error messages.
raise @ticket.errors.inspect in else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the user_id attribute when making the POST request

And it's because of this line:

```
 <td><%= f.label :user_id, "User Name" %></td>
```

you meant to write

```
 <td><%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id  %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did work and allowed the POST to go through successfully. What I was intentionally only using it for was to display the Users name in the 1st row of the table but I have already altered it to show the current users user name elsewhere. thanks again!